# How to draw an arc in universal windows app

Tags: windows, windows-phone, drawing, win-universal-app

I need an arc (circle segment) in my universal windows application, but i just cant figure it out how to make it. There are only circle and rectangle shapes available. My goal is to create an arc that is showing the given percent, line 50% 66% etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want something like this:

[image: arc control]

Check my solution (tested on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 UWP):

https://github.com/arek-kubiak/ArcControl/tree/master

I hope it will be helpful for you :) 
Be careful, control automatically adjusts the height and width to the radius and thickness. (if you will have some problems i can help :))

Comment: Yes, i wanted to achieve something like this exactly, thanks!

Comment: @Arek I know that this is for Universal Apps,but can I use this in Windows Phone 8 apps?

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Arek!

Comment: is there a way to fill the Content of the circle with another Color?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to create complex shapes in XAML, you'll probably want to take a look at the windows.ui.xaml.shapes.path class. It can use a complex object model to specify [bezier curves](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185585.aspx) which should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a an arc segment such as one used in a gauge control, It appears  Diederik Krols has your answer:

http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/11/14/Drawing-a-Circular-Gradient-in-Windows-Store-and-Windows-Phone-apps.aspx