# Create a Stopwatch Counter Control in Windows 10 Mobile App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, stopwatch, windows-10-mobile

I'm currently working on Windows 10 Mobile App

And I want to make a stopwatch like this:
[image]

I followed this tutorial: [Create a StopWatch Counter control in WPF(XAML)](http://dotnetvisio.blogspot.co.il/2014/06/create-stopwatch-counter-control-in.html)

But I'm working on Windows 10, so I can't use `IMultiValueConverter`

Any suggestion to help me go through this.. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you can start [with this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23046565/2681948).

Comment: The problem is I can't use **IMultiValueConverter** :( and the tutorial you gave me used IMultiValueConverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something with what you can start - [in this post Arek Kubiak liked source to his arc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32740136/2681948) which can be used for example like this:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" xmlns:arc="using:ArcControl">
    <Grid Width="80" Height="80">
        <arc:Arc Thickness="3" Fill="Blue"  PercentValue="{Binding Percent}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Percent}" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    private int percent = 0;
    public int Percent
    {
        get { return percent; }
        set { percent = value; RaiseProperty(nameof(Percent)); }
    }

    private DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25) };

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        timer.Tick += (s, e) => { Percent++; if (Percent > 99) Percent = 0; };
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

The result: [image]

Of course it still needs much more work to make it better, fit your needs, but there are lots of blogs/posts about circular/radial controls. You can take a look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23047288/2681948), [this blog](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/02/07/a-circular-progressbar-style-using-an-attached-viewmodel.html) and default *ProgressBar*'s style. With those you can design your own control with suitable *VisualStates* and transition that will look like you just want it.